# How can I solve a Sympy equation with multiple equals?

Tags: python, sympy, equation

*x1/A = x2/B = x3/C = x4/D = Constant* :
Is the type of equation I want to solve automatically.

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

def _3covoit_prop(CostList): # Costs : [A,B,C,D]
    n = len(CostList)
    varbs = symbols('x(:'+str(n)+')') #(x0, x1, x2, x3)
    eqs = [ (x/cout) for x,cout in zip(varbs,CostList) ]
    maxLC = max(CostList)
    E = Eq(eqs[0],maxLC)
    for e in eqs[0:] :
        E = Eq(e,E,evaluate=False) #equal imbrication here
    s=solve(E, varbs)

_3covoit_prop([100.,450.,500.,1450.])
```

Gives a very strange answer. If anyone has an idea to help, it would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the equations in a list in the form of `[Eq(x1/A, Constant),  Eq(x2/B, Constant), Eq(x3/C, Constant), Eq(x4/D, Constant)]`. And then call `solve` on that list.

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

def _3covoit_prop(CostList):  # Costs : [A,B,C,D]
    n = len(CostList)
    varbs = symbols('x(:' + str(n) + ')')  # (x0, x1, x2, x3)
    eqs = [(x / cout) for x, cout in zip(varbs, CostList)]
    maxLC = max(CostList)
    E = [Eq(equation, maxLC) for equation in eqs]
    s = solve(E, varbs)
    return s

s = _3covoit_prop([100., 450., 500., 1450.])
print(s)
```

Outputs:

```py
{x0: 145000.000000000,
 x1: 652500.000000000,
 x2: 725000.000000000,
 x3: 2102500.00000000}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that's the solution I just found too ;)

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/22454